# How to add a parameter for purchased item to Firebase in_app_purchase event?

Tags: firebase, firebase-analytics

Is there any way to add a parameter to Firebase in_app_purchase event? Because one can create dynamic in-app purchases, it is not possible to separate different purchases with just product_id or product_name.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.ITEM_ID , "Item ID");
bundle.putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.ITEM_NAME , "Item Name");
bundle.putDouble(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.PRICE , Price);
bundle.putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.ITEM_CATEGORY , "Item Category");
mAnalytics.logEvent(FirebaseAnalytics.Event.PURCHASE , bundle);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).